# Position vector in terms of a given velocity

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it correct to say that, given $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$, a point on a curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be given by $$\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)+(t-t_0)\dot{\gamma}(t)$$ for all $t>t_0$? I'm guessing not since the velocity is not assumed constant...so is there a way of expressing any point on a curve given a fixed point on a curve and its velocity?

Comment: The above is correct. Velocity by definition is the first derivative of the curve (position). The acceleration (caused by external forces) is the second derivative by definition. There might be even higher derivative consideration as the force may adhere to a complicated function... so I think your initial claim works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, however this is a good approximation for $|t-t_0|$ small if you take $\dot{\gamma}(t_0)$ instead of $\dot{\gamma}(t).$ Indeed, this would be the first terms of a Taylor approximation

Comment: yeah my friend just mentioned the similarity to Taylor and this would imply the existence of a remainder term...though I guess in the case of  constant velocity the above would hold exactly, since all higher order terms would vanish?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Intuitively, if the first derivative is constant, then there is no acceleration in any direction, so that your curve is actually a straight line that you travel at a constant velocity. So calculating where you land after a time $t-t_0$ is obvious.